# I want to display encoded url that I pass to this page

Tags: php

I want to print encoded url with the help of echo, for example I send variables like this:

```
"http://www.indiandeal.in/test.php?go=http://www.facebook.com/indiandeal"
```

It is working fine if I pass any variable but not with encoded url string. Normal url string works fine.

i don't want to encode the url.
i want this to work

http://www.indiandeal.in/test.php?go=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal&123=234

this should print the url as

www facebook com indiandeal&123=234

but it displaying only

http www facebook com/indiandeal

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$txt1 = $_GET["go"];
echo $txt1;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you asking a question or giving your explaination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

A querystring may contain several `key-value` pairs. When there is more than one key-value pair, they are typically separated by ampersands `(&)`.

**input :**

```
http://www.indiandeal.in/test.php?go=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal&123=234
```

Here, `$_GET["go"]` only gives you the value associated with `go`.For access the whole query string you have to use this :

The raw, unprocessed query string can be retrieved by the QUERY_STRING server variable:

```
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: i don't want to encode the url.

i want this to work

http://www.indiandeal.in/test.php?go=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal

this should print the encoded url as it is already encoded.

Comment: @SushantKathuria, I updated my answer.Please check i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an encoded url it will automatically be **[decoded](http://php.net/urldecode)**

> Warning
>
> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.
> Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have
> unexpected and dangerous results.

If you still want to see it encoded you can use **[urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode)**

**Edit based on your comment.**

If you want to save the encoded version of your request variable named `go` you can do

```
echo urlencode($_GET['go']);  // this encodes it again

//echo urlencode("http://www.facebook.com/indiandeal");
```

**Output**

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal
```

Comment: I want to pass encoded url to go variable. I don't want to encode

Comment: i don't want to encode the url.

i want this to work

http://www.indiandeal.in/test.php?go=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal

this should print the encoded url as it is already encoded.

Comment: So whats wrong with it? it works. it gives you the decoded version `http://www.facebook.com/indiandeal`. And if you want to keep the encoded version then yes you have to encode it like this answer does `echo urlencode($_GET['go']);`

Comment: Nope, think you failed to RTFM. It will automatically be decoded and you cant get around that if you use `$_GET`, to use it as it is you have to encode it again or use raw http request methods

Comment: the problem is i want to send "&" in my encoded url
for example when i send this 

http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Findiandeal&asd